# What is the PS3 Jailbreak?

Tags: ps3

I've been hearing about this "PS3 Jailbreak" but haven't found any info on what it actually does. [PSGroove](http://psgroove.com/) is what it's called, but what does it allow you to do?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, If Mark's answer helped you, don't forget you can 'accept' it by clicking the checkmark under the vote count. :-)

Comment: Wow. It's been years. I had completely forgotten about this. Thanks for the bump lol.

Comment: haha no problem :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main functions that PS3 Jailbreak provides are:

1. Ability to run your own code on a PS3 - you normally can't do this.
2. Ability to copy games to your hard disk, and run copied disks

PSGroove apparently has limitations that restrict its use to run pirate games. see: http://www.thesixthaxis.com/2010/09/01/psjailbreak-open-sourced/